Openssl versión 3 no abre certificado .pfx
actualice de servidor en Hostinger, y note que la versión de openssl que tienen es versión 3; anteriormente estaba con la versión 1.1 la cual no presentaba problemas, pero ahora no puedo leer la información de mi certificado .pfx, ayuda. Hay otra forma de leer mas actualizada?? con open ssl  versión 3??

Estás intentando leerlo por línea de comando o desde una app?
